# Let $S = \{\frac{n^2+\sqrt{5}}{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $f : \mathbb{N} \to S$ be defined by $f(n) = \frac{n^2+\sqrt{5}}{n}$. Show $f$ is injective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I am really confused on this one. I am not sure how exactly to proceed. Furthermore, is my understanding of functions and mapping misguided or is this function not one-to-one on $S$?

When I graph $f(n)$, it's clear to see that $f(1) = f(2.236) = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1}$, and doesn't $f : \mathbb{N} \to S$ mean that the inputs lie within $\mathbb{N}$ (so $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$) and all the outputs are in the form $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1}, \frac{2+\sqrt{5}}{2}, ...$ for all values of $\mathbb{N}$? Clearly, there is an output shared for two values of $n$, rending this not one-to-one?

Here is my work thus far:

Suppose $x, y, \in \mathbb{N}$, then

$\frac{x^2+\sqrt{5}}{x} = \frac{y^2+\sqrt{5}}{y}$

$ = x + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{x} = \ y + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{y}$

$ = x - y = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{x} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{y}$

I do not know how else to continue.

Comment: I don't undertand your proposed counterexample.  $2.236$ is not in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: What you are asked to prove is that, given $m,n\in \mathbb N$  then $f(m)=f(n)\implies m=n$.

Comment: Why didn't you write those as $\frac {x^2 +\sqrt 5}x, \frac {y^2 + \sqrt 5}y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{x^{\color{red}2}+\sqrt{5}}{x} = \frac{y^{\color{red}2}+\sqrt{5}}{y}$ (not $\frac{x+\sqrt{5}}{x} = \frac{y+\sqrt{5}}{y}$)

$\color{red}\implies x + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{x} = \ y + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{y}$ (not "equals"; "implies")

$\color{red}\implies x - y = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{x} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{y}$.

Okay mulitply both sides by $xy$.

$x^2y - y^2 x = \sqrt{5}x - \sqrt 5y$

$xy(x-y) = \sqrt{5} (x-y)$.

Now we have two cases:

Case 1:  $x-y = 0$.

If so.... then $x = y$.  GO home have a beer we are done.

Case 2: $x-y \ne 0$.

If so we can divide both sides by $x-y$.

$xy = \sqrt 5$.

But $x, y\in \mathbb N$  so $xy \in \mathbb N$.  But $\sqrt 5\not \in \mathbb N$ so....

This is impossible.

We *don't* have case 2:

We *only* have case 1:.

So $x-y = 0$.

And $x = y$.

Is the beer still cold?

Answer (score 1):

$$x-y= \left( \frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{y} \right) \cdot \sqrt{5}$$
$$x-y = \left( \frac{y-x}{xy} \right) \cdot \sqrt{5}$$
$$xy(x-y) = \left( y-x \right) \cdot \sqrt{5}$$
If $x \neq y$ then you can divide both sides by $x-y$ to get
$$xy = -\sqrt{5}$$
A contradicition (for example, because $xy$ is an integer, while $- \sqrt{5}$ is not).

To avoid contradiction you necessarily need $x=y$. This means that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$f(n) = \frac{n^2+\sqrt{5}}{n}$$

It sufficess to show the sequence is increasing.

$$f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{(n+1)^2+\sqrt{5}}{n+1}-\frac{n^2+\sqrt{5}}{n}$$

$$=\frac{((n+1)^2+\sqrt{5})n-(n^2-\sqrt{5})(n+1)}{(n+1)n}$$

$$=\frac{2n^2-\sqrt 5}{(n+1)n}>0$$

And check the first values.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, the function is $f(n)=\frac{n^2+\sqrt5}{n}$, (you calculated with $f(n)=\frac{n+\sqrt 5}{n}$); so you are actually equating : $$\frac{x^2+\sqrt 5}{x}-\frac{y^2+\sqrt5}{y}=0\implies \frac{x^2y+y\sqrt5-xy^2-x\sqrt5}{xy}=0$$
$$\implies\frac{(xy)(x-y)-\sqrt5(x-y)}{xy}=0\implies(x-y)(1-\frac{\sqrt5}{xy})=0$$

This either gives $x=y$ or $xy=\sqrt 5\implies x\cup y \notin\Bbb N$.